# MySQL order is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

At the moment I'm building a market info query. here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    `data`.s AS Simbol,
    format( ( (`data`.c - `data`.p) / `data`.p ), 3 ) AS pctChange, 
    lu
FROM 
    jos_marketinfo AS `data`
WHERE 
    `data`.s LIKE '%.%' 
ORDER BY pctChange ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

As you see, I'm calculating percentage change in the query and I would like to reorder it.
The problem arise that the order is false, I see big negative pctChange value in middle and vice verse.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: how is it possible to see without sample data? Try reversing data.c and p. Also whats wrong with negative pc change?

Comment: maybe you could paste your table, just for bigger picture?! it will be from great help for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by without format to avoid alphabetic order and get numeric order:

```
ORDER BY (data.c-data.p)/data.p
```

Comment: +1 From [FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format): *returns the result as a string*

Comment: Hola Álvaro, gracias por documentar la respuesta.